# Mac Automator variable not working as expected

Tags: macos, automator

I've created a workflow in Automator that isn't working as expected.

I started with an 'ask for text' action and a 'set value of variable' action (ProductCode). Then a 'New folder' action using that variable as part of the name and that works fine giving me (ProductCode)_Master Folder.

The trouble I'm having is using the variable again, when I use the (ProductCode) variable to name another folder, I'm just getting $(6BF6D2D6-19E6-474A-99CC-78F5F7F8E44F) instead of the (ProductCode).

Here's a screen grab of the workflow with results. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Workflow screen grab]

Comment: Now that is weird—so the variable returns something totally different the second time you use it, even though you don't set it between those two uses. This might be an Automator bug. (A really bad one!)

Comment: ...what happens if you save the second folder in a different location? I wonder if it's doing this because you can't have two folders in the same location with the same name?

Comment: Still the same thing unfortunately :(

Comment: If you wanted to post the Workflow somewhere, I'm curious to see what will happen if I run it in my much older version of Automator.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy, RE: "I wonder if it's doing this because you can't have two folders in the same location with the same name?" --  The **Automator** _workflow_ pictured in the OP **is not** attempting to create two _folders_ with the same _name_. It is clearly attempting to create two _folders_ with different _names_. One called **[ProductCode]_Main Folder** and the other **[ProductCode]_New Folder**.

Comment: The Haunted 1, I have tested your **Automator** _workflow_ under **macOS Big Sur** 11.3.1 and it worked without issue. It created **[ProductCode]_Main Folder** and **[ProductCode]_New Folder**, where the value of **[ProductCode]** was **1234**.

Comment: It's strange I'm using macOS Big Sur 11.3.1 (Automator Version 2.10 (509)) and it keeps happening, I even transferred it to my workMac and that's using macOS Catalina, the same happens.

Comment: As I said, I'd be interested to get a copy of the actual `.workflow` file, as opposed to just the steps, if you don't mind throwing that up somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Services/Quick Actions are saved in Library/Services.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy, RE: "are saved in Library/Services." --  They are saved in **~/Library/Services**. Also the OP asked in his comment "Sorry, how would I go about doing that?" an it would be so much better if you'd actually explained that the best thing to do is compress the `.workflow` as it's a _document bundle_ not an individual _file_. Then upload  the _zip archive_ to a _file sharing service_ and provide a **URL** to download from. Additionally, the fact that I cannot reproduce the issue, it might be best if he first deletes the original and recreates it. Then see if the issue persists.

Comment: @The Haunted 1, See my previous comment to Wowfunhapp  and if you do not have a  _file sharing service_ already, you can use [https://gofile.io](https://gofile.io) for a free upload. Before doing anything, since I cannot reproduce the issue, have your tried deleting the original **Automator** _Service/Quick Action_ and then recreate it from scratch? If not I'd try that first. Also I'd reboot the system.

Comment: Thank you for the file sharing service information.

I am so sorry, looks like @user3439894 was correct. I recreated the workflow and it seems to work as expected. I had created it 2 or 3 times before and had the same problem.... I do it this morning and it works. Thank you both for your time and help. I feel so silly now.

Answer (score 1):

I realised why the variable wasn't working when using it a second time. There was a space at the start of the folders name.